# Persist user options, React

Tags: reactjs, django, jwt

I am using JWT in a React-Django app to handle user authentication. I can register, login, and logout successfully. However, user data does not persist on the frontend. All of the tutorials and articles I've seen online suggest storing user data in local storage to persist the data, but I've also heard this isn't an excellent choice. Is there a better option? Can y'all point me towards articles/resources that cover any better options?

Comment: You need to expand on what "user data" consists of in your use case to advise correctly.

Comment: like username, email

Comment: And, just to make sure before I answer -- that is coming from the back end right? Also if you could specify what is currently contained in your JWT? Do you have an API available to query your users information?

Comment: If you are using JWT, then you can have the basic user information in the payload itself, so you would not have to store it anywhere else or make calls to API again and again to get the user data. You can either use Local Storage, Session Storage or Cookies for persisting the data, each having its trade-off. You can make the analysis on your own based on your use case.